# Zend A 404 error occurred Page not found

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-studio

I am new to zend frame work. I am in the process of learning this, in fact at the very beginning of this. My problem is that I download the zend studio and try to run the zend application by following a tutorial on net but the when I run the code it said that

'**A 404 error occurred
Page not found The requested URL could not be matched by routing** '.

I googled man time and applied all the possible solutions on it but all in vein. Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: please list out "all the possible solutions", a.k.a. what you have tried

Comment: by verifying the config file from different resources on for the router. By checking whether zend studio is integrated with the zend framework. plus by checking whether zend server is running or not.

Comment: For reference http://files.zend.com/help/Beta/Zend_Studio_9_0/Tutorials/running_applications_on_local_zend_servers.htm 

This is the link I was following

Comment: could you show the configs ?

Comment: There is an error of **zend framework 2.2.1**

Comment: Which code is producing the error??? whats the name of your controller and how are you trying to access it???

Comment: When I selecting the framework version from zend studio, if it is zend framework 2.2.1 than it won't work if I select 1.12.3 than it works. I don't know why....

Comment: Your are simplifying things here.... You cannot just assume zendframework2 working as zendframework1 the whole core functionality works diffrent. I do have litle to no expirience with zendstudio nor would I want to pay that ammount to use it but by all means can't you just do the simple album application from the documentation? Can't you just set/configure/deploy your zend2 project? It really is not that hard. http://framework.zend.com/learn/ go here and start from the top. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

To Do list:

1. check your server folder permission -> 777 for the development
2. check .htaccess file in the public folder, there is a good example .htaccess files for Zend in here stackoverflow
3. check your php configuration for model rewrite, unlikely sometimes it does not install
4. check your apache site-enable file for model rewrite and allowaccess

you need to google them out, but that is it, after you finish your first one , all other project just copy from the first one